# Trouble loading a dataset in R

Tags: r

I have downloaded the package SemiPar and I have been trying to attach the dataset fuel.frame, using the command data(fuel.frame), but without sucess. The error I have been getting is:

```
Error in read.table(zfile, header = TRUE, as.is = FALSE) : 
  more columns than column names
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In read.table(zfile, header = TRUE, as.is = FALSE) :
  line 1 appears to contain embedded nulls
2: In read.table(zfile, header = TRUE, as.is = FALSE) :
  line 5 appears to contain embedded nulls
3: In read.table(zfile, header = TRUE, as.is = FALSE) :
  incomplete final line found by readTableHeader on 'C:/...
```

Could you please tell me what is wrong here? I have tried to look for solutions online but it seems the package works for everyone besides myself.

My sessionInfo()

```
attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base 


other attached packages:
[1] SemiPar_1.0-4.1

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] cluster_1.15.3  grid_3.1.1      lattice_0.20-29 MASS_7.3-33     nlme_3.1-117   
[6] tools_3.1.1
```

Thank you.

Comment: The error message is telling you that the header row has fewer column names than the number of columns of data. Can you post the first few rows of the data file you're trying to load and the code you're running?

Comment: What character is delimiting your  columns? Do you use `.` or `,` for decimal numbers?

Comment: @eipi10 Unfortunately I do not know, what the dataset looks like since I cannot load it. But the package containing it is freely available. Would you mind trying to see if you can load it on your system?

Comment: Use readLines to read by lines (sep by /n) and do some analysis on the data structures. I have had similar case when it was a csv file containing responses that had commas.

Comment: Did you try `library(SemiPar); data(fuel.frame)`?

Comment: @nrussell Yes of course and this is the error I have been getting.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik How can I verify that? I just used data(fuel.frame).

Comment: @JohnK Okay that wasn't clear since you did not include that in your question. Can you post your `sessionInfo()` please?

Comment: Per @nrussell's comment, you don't need `read.table` to load a data frame that's contained in an `R` package. Are you saying you're getting an error when you run `data(fuel.frame)`?

Comment: @eipi10 Yes, precisely. Wasn't that supposed to work?

Comment: @nrussell Certainly, please see my edited post.

Comment: Yes. It should have worked (and it works for me). What happens if you reinstall `SemiPar` and restart your `R` session?

Comment: @eipi10 Same error unfortunately...Note that I can load the datasets from the package datasets using data() without any complications

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "fuel.frame" file is actually in the ../SemiPar/data/ directory wherever your library is. You can use the `.libPaths()` function. For me it returns:

```
> .libPaths()
[1] "/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.1/Resources/library"
```

If you look in there you should see "fuel.frame.txt.gz" which tells you that it's a gzipped file that will expand to a text file (which is what the `data()` call is doing before passing it to `read.table()` ). The top of it looks like:

```
            car.name         Weight Disp. Mileage     Fuel    Type 
           "Eagle Summit 4"   2560    97      33 3.030303   Small
            "Ford Escort 4"   2345   114      33 3.030303   Small
           "Ford Festiva 4"   1845    81      37 2.702703   Small
            "Honda Civic 4"   2260    91      32 3.125000   Small
          "Mazda Protege 4"   2440   113      32 3.125000   Small
         "Mercury Tracer 4"   2285    97      26 3.846154   Small
          "Nissan Sentra 4"   2275    97      33 3.030303   Small
         "Pontiac LeMans 4"   2350    98      28 3.571429   Small
```

As you can see your error message is not correct about my copy. So you may want to use your unnamed system to expand the .gz file and investigate. (I was not getting an error with my R 3.1.1 (SnowLeopard build) running in OSX 10.7.5.) With my setup this also succeeds:

```
 data('fuel.frame', 
     lib.loc='/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.1/Resources/library/')
```

Comment: I have two libraries. I can open datasets from the package datasets just fine using the data() command. The problem only arises with the package SemiPar.

Comment: I have also exported a dataset onto my desktop. R can read it just fine, using the command read.table(). I think there is something wrong with my second library.

Comment: Do you maybe have two SemiPar directories?

Comment: Nop but my datasets package is in my first library and that works fine. On the contrary, my SemiPar in my second library is problematic.

Comment: Could you please tell me how can I delete my second (working) library and tell R to use just the first?

Comment: You don't need to delete the second. You can just change the library  path with:.............. `.libPaths( .libPaths()[1] )`. Then if you are happy with the change you can delete them to save space. I run with only one library. I think the extra libraries are designed for Windows users who have trouble with permissions when using R in corporate environments.